# Copy elements from fread into a structure

Tags: c++, fread, memcpy

I am reading slices from a file like so:

```
unsigned short vol_buffer[vol_buffer_size]; //vol_buffer_size = SLICE_SIZE * 4. SLICE_SIZE = 759000 bytes

for (int j = 0; j < num_slps; j++){ //num_slps is 138 in this case
    nItemsRead = fread(&vol_buffer, SLICE_SIZE, 4, volFile);

}
```

I want to copy the data from the vol_buffer into the slices array in the SliceProjLinePair structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    SliceHeaders slice_headers[4];
    unsigned short slices[4][RECON_IMG_NUM_X*RECON_IMG_NUM_Y]; // slice data
    unsigned short proj_lines_00[6][NUM_PROJ_COLS]; // 0 deg proj image lines
    unsigned short proj_lines_90[6][NUM_PROJ_COLS]; // 90 deg proj image lines
}__attribute__((packed)) SliceProjLinePair;
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
SliceProjLinePair *slice_packet;

memcpy(slice_packet->slices, &vol_buffer, vol_buffer_size);
```

But this memcpy crashes. How do I get the data from the buffer to fit into the slices array?

Edit: I'm now allocating the struct like so:

```
 SliceProjLinePair *slice_packet = new SliceProjLinePair();
```

and it is not crashing but it is only filling up values in slices[0]. I want it to fill out values in slices[0] through slices[3].

Comment: The memcpy can crash if the destination area is not allowed, or if the source area size (vol_buffer_size) is bigger than the destination area (slice_packet->slices). How you allocate memory for slice_packet->slices ?

Comment: The code above does not allocate `slice_packet` (e.g. `slice_packet = new SliceProjLinePair();`), so it looks like `slice_packet->slices` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dan What is the value of RECON_IMG_NUM_X and RECON_IMG_NUM_Y ?

Comment: Something like `valgrind` is appropriate for debugging read/write access errors as this almost certainly is.

Comment: @Landstalker I guess I'm not allocating it properly. How would I do that? also the value of RECON_IMG_NUM_X and Y are 690 and 550.

Comment: I think `SLICE_SIZE` should be `sizeof(unsigned short) * RECON_IMG_NUM_X*RECON_IMG_NUM_Y`

Also are you thinking that `sizeof(vol_buffer) == vol_buffer_size` ??

Comment: @Sumit I think you are right. I will edit the size that I want to read. Also do I even need the intermediate step of reading into a buffer? Can I just do an fread straight into slice_packet->slices?

Comment: you can pass any valid address of ample size to fread(), so you should be able to do it direct.
And If you finally come to conclusion that `SLICE_SIZE` should be `sizeof(unsigned short) * RECON_IMG_NUM_X*RECON_IMG_NUM_Y` then in `memcpy` the 3rd arg would be `SLICE_SIZE * nItemsRead` or may be `sizeof(vol_buffer)`
On the other hand I would personally recommend to read only 1 record instead of 4 at a time through fread, for the time being(at-least till it has no bug).